# PowerShell properties issues

Tags: powershell

```
$History = $ServerRequest.$_.24hr_work
```

The `24hr_work` part comes up with missing property name after reference operator error.

I have tried `$ServerRequest.$_.'24hr_work'` and even tried having an object point to it.

```
$24 = '24hr_work'
```

When I type it, I get errors right after the 24, so I believe the number is the issue, I just can't find another way to write it. It has something to do with the property starting with a number.

Comment: What are the values of `$ServerRequest` and `$_`? What are their properties?

Comment: They work. Right above this I have $Name = ServerRequest.$_.Name

Comment: It's kind of long to write out, but its a webrequest which gets api data, then the $_ is the foreach argument that was ran with get member | select | foreach.  Like "Time":12:01,"Name":Todo,  etc.

Comment: The issue is purely with the "24hr"....If I type any number than letter it throws out an error like "22mh" for example. It seems like starting it with a number is the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed: In order to refer to a property whose name starts with a *digit* (`0`, `1`, ... `9`) you must:

- either: use *quoting* around the *literal* property name.
- or: use a *variable* to provide the property name *indirectly*.

To demonstrate:

```
$obj = [pscustomobject] @{ '1a' = '1a''s value' }

# !! BREAKS, because the property name starts with a digit.
$obj.1a

# OK: Quote the property name
$obj.'1a'
$obj."1a"

# OK: Access the property via  a *variable*
$propName = '1a'
$obj.$propName
```

This implies that accessing property `24hr_work` via variable `$24` containing that string *should* work, however [*update: since confirmed to work by the OP*].